# npm start command can't find json file in npm v3.10.8

Tags: json, node.js, npm

While starting the `npm` it's giving below error, seems it is not able to find the json file, kindly check below details along with log file

```
simplymacs-MacBook-Air-2:hackoregon_component_library
MelissaKeith$ npm "start"
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.8.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.8.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path /Users/MelissaKeith/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MelissaKeith/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MelissaKeith/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/MelissaKeith/hackoregon_component_library/npm-debug.log
```

**npm-debug.log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.8.1/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.8
3 info using node@v6.8.1
4 verbose config Skipping project config: /Users/MelissaKeith/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MelissaKeith/package.json'
5 verbose stack     at Error (native)
6 verbose cwd /Users/MelissaKeith/hackoregon_component_library
7 error Darwin 15.6.0
8 error argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.8.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
9 error node v6.8.1
10 error npm  v3.10.8
11 error path /Users/MelissaKeith/package.json
12 error code ENOENT
13 error errno -2
14 error syscall open
15 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MelissaKeith/package.json'
16 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MelissaKeith/package.json'
16 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
16 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
17 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

Comment: Is there a `package.json` file in the directory you are running `npm start` in?

Comment: Where's your `package.json`?

Comment: There is a package.json file and its in the main file of the directory

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. Removing the entire node_modules folder and re-installing worked for me.This problem occurs when you are installing a old module(as written in your package.json) but it is not available on git due to update in their version:

for solving this issue.

```
 rm -rf node_modules
 npm install
```

Comment: How would I check if my module was out of date with the github? And what do you mean by node_module in this situation?

Comment: simplymacs-MacBook-Air-2:hackoregon_component_library MelissaKeith$ rm -rf node_modules
simplymacs-MacBook-Air-2:hackoregon_component_library MelissaKeith$ npm install
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MelissaKeith/package.json'
npm WARN MelissaKeith No description
npm WARN MelissaKeith No repository field.
npm WARN MelissaKeith No README data
npm WARN MelissaKeith No license field.

Comment: there is a module 'npm-check',which Check for outdated, incorrect, and unused dependencies. https://github.com/dylang/npm-check

Comment: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MelissaKeith/package.json' , this means the package is not available as you can see in your node_modules folder